Psychedelic sci-fi movie about televisions sucking people into tv shows
This is a movie I watched about 15 years ago. Was looking for it all over the IMDB, but no luck. I don't remember the whole plot, but here is small scene that I can remember:
...A guy breaks an electricity cables box to shut the electricity off in a TV store. Then, he goes into that store and buys all available manufacturers' TV remotes. Meanwhile the electricity box is being repaired by the shop staff. The guy wants to run, but he is reminded about the batteries for the remotes. He buys the batteries in a hurry, throws them in a package on top of the remotes and runs to the exit. The package breaks, the content of the package (TV remotes and batteries) are falling down. The guy grabs everything he can with bare hands and runs out. TVs are getting back online, as the electricity restored. TV start emitting some blue rays, but the guy avoid them, jumps in a trunk of a pickup and is safely away...
Some more memories about the plot: The TVs were "sucking" people into some psychedelic dreamworld.

Stay Tuned? Pleasantville?

Sorry, but neither of them. Let's say that it is more horror than comedy or drama. Oh, and it is not "Videodrome" either.

Wes Craven's "Shocker" had two people battling each other while moving from one television channel to the next, and the villain was eventually defeated by a device constructed from TV remotes.  It came out in 1989, though, well before "Titanic".

Yeah, BasicWolf, do you mean it features\references the movie Titanic? Because then we'll know for sure that it came out after 1998.

Guys, I've updated the question (removed the Titanic line, as it might be misleading there). The Titanic as I remember was not a reference to Cameron's "Titanic", nor to any other Titanic movie. It's nose appeared in one scene. The ship was parked in a port, and the all weird people and creatures on board were putting a lifeboat with a film's hero from the ship saying "good-bye". As I said, extremely psychedelic.

Really interesting one! I'm curious what this could be, too. Not that it's anything more than a hunch, but seems like a TV movie/episode... do you remember what medium you saw it in?

This is the Czech film Akumulátor 1 (1993), directed by Jan Svěrák. No wonder it was hard to find it :)



